# XmlSerializers raises BindingFailure

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization, dll

I'm trying to serialize a "PrinterSettings" using this code:

```
Private Sub pAddEditPrinterSettings(ByVal uPrinterSettings As PrinterSettings)

    Dim s As String = String.Empty

    Dim nXSer As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(uPrinterSettings.GetType())
    Using sw As New StringWriter
        nXSer.Serialize(sw, uPrinterSettings)
        s = sw.ToString()
    End Using
```

However, the line "nXSer As New ..." fails with the error

```
BindingFailure: The assembly with the name "System.Drawing.XmlSerializers" wasn't found in the LoadFrom binding contexts of AppDomain with ID 1. Cause: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The file or assembly "SystemDrawing.XmlSerializers, Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken b03f5f7f11d50a3a or a dependency wasn't found. The system couldn't find the file.
```

What might I be doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In another post I read that this is normal and can just be ignored by unticking "Throw error at this exception".
Not beautiful, but there doesn't seem to be any workaround as of 2018.

Comment: FYI you can just create a comment under your initial question, or edit your question instead of writing a new answer.